# Amount of reward I get until the first heads

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I play a simple game which is modeled as follows:

I've a coin with heads probability $p$. I flip it and then give myself 1 coin with probability $p_w$ (if tails, I get nothing). Then I check the coin, if it's heads I stop, otherwise I continue until I get heads.

Let $R$ denote the number of coins I got when the game terminates.
I'd like to calculate $E(R)$ and $Var(R)$. My attempt was as follows.

Let $N$ denote the number of rounds until I get a heads and $X$ denote the number of coins I get in a round. We have $R = N\cdot X$.
We further have $N \sim Geom(p)$ and $X \sim Bern(p_w)$. Since $N$ and $X$ independent we can write,

$$ E(R) = E(N)\cdot E(X),$$ 
$$Var(R) =  E(X)^2\cdot Var(N) + E(N)^2 \cdot Var(X) + Var(X)\cdot Var(N).$$

Finally, plugging the values yield.
$$ E(R) = p_w / p $$
$$ Var(R) = \frac{p_w(2 - p - p_w)}{p^2} $$

I think the expected value is sound however, variance does't make any sense to me. I feel that the only thing that matters is the ratio $\frac{p_w}{p}$ but value of variance changes with actual values of probabilities.

In particular, we can have $E(R) - StdDev(R)$ negative in some cases which doesn't make any sense.

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Even for a process that never returns negative numbers, there's nothing inherently contradictory about $E(X) < StdDev(X)$ (or, equivalently in this case, $[E(X)]^2 < Var(X)$) so long as the distribution for $X$ is skewed.  For example, if $X$ is selected from $0, ..., n$ such that 0 is selected with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and $1, ..., n$ are selected with probability $\frac{1}{2n}$, then we have $Var(X) = \frac{1}{48}(n+1)(5n+1)$ while $E(X) = \frac{1}{4}(n+1)$.  In this case, $Var(X) > [E(X)]^2$ for $n > 1$.

Comment: The reward is always positive. How can a negative one be bounds within std.dev? Isn't that illogical?

Comment: @spiderrico It is possible for a distribution that can only be nonnegative to have negative numbers within one standard deviation of the mean. In fact it's the case for the Bernoulli distribution with $p<1/2.$ This is ok... it's just soreness.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen:  That is a much nicer example than mine.  Another better-known one is the Poisson distribution with $\lambda < 1$.

Comment: @spiderrico I mean skewness! (Of course it autocorrected and was just in time for the 5 minute window to edit comments.)

Comment: I see. Seemed pretty counter-intuitive initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are missing something. Your equation $R=NX$ is not coherent. You say $X$ is "the number of coins you get in a round" but what does that even mean? You have a random number $N$ different rounds and on each round you get some number $X_i$ of coins. Thus you should write $$ R= \sum_{i=1}^N X_i.$$

For help doing calculations where the number of elements in the sum is random, perhaps google Wald's theorem, which states that in fact your answer for expected value is correct. The secret is basically using conditional probability carefully.

Comment: I see my error now. In a round, you either get 1 coin or 0 by the way.

Comment: Also, how can I compute the variance of R in this case? How many terms are there r.h.s when I take Var of both sides ?

Comment: Ok, got that here also: http://www.math.unl.edu/~sdunbar1/ProbabilityTheory/Lessons/Conditionals/RandomSums/randsum.shtml

Comment: @spiderRico That link you found answers your question, right?